# Estimate to arrive at $\mathbb{E}[(|X^{i}_t|+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N|X^j_t|)^q\mid X_0^{i}=x]\leq C x^q$

Tags: conditional-expectation, estimation, stochastic-differential-equations

**Setup**
We have a system of $N$ diffusion processes described by
$$X_t^{i}=X_0^{i}+\int_0^t \mu(s,X_s)ds+\int_0^t\sigma(s,X_s)dW^{i}_s,$$
with the Brownian motions $W^{i}$ as well as the drift $\mu$ and the volatility $\sigma$ with sufficient regularity (e.g. Lipschitz condition and sublinear growth) for strong uniqueness and existence of a solution.

On this basis, define the process
$$\Lambda_t^{i}=|X_t^{i}|+1/N\sum_{j=1}^N|X_t^{j}|,$$

and assume it to be Sub-Gaussian distributed (i.e. we can find a Gaussian random variable as an upper bound).

**Problem**
In this setup I'd like to get the estimation
\begin{equation}\label{thing}
 \mathbb{E}[(1+\Lambda_i^q)\mid X_0^{i}=x]\leq C(1+x^q)\quad \text{where }C>0\text{, }q>1\text{ and }x\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

**Idea**
The basic idea for proving this was using Gronwall's inequality in the monotonic case. So if I could estimate
$$\Lambda_t^{i}\leq\alpha(t)+\int_0^t\beta(s)\Lambda_s^{i}ds,$$
for $\alpha$ monotonoically increasing, that would give me
$$\Lambda_t^{i}\leq \alpha(t)e^{\int_0^t\beta(s)ds}.$$
My approach would be to choose $\alpha(t)=X_0^{i}$ or $\alpha(t)=X_0^{i}+1/N\sum_{j=1}^N X_0^{j}$ for some $\beta$ I'm not able to find. But it would yield
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[1+(\Lambda_t^{i})^q)|X_0^{i}=x]\leq (1+Cx^q)
\end{align}
for some constant, since sub-gaussianity of $\Lambda_t^{i}$ implies sub-gaussianity of the $X_t^j$ represented by this constant $C$.

**Question**
Do you have any idea how to use Gronwall's inequality in this case, how to choose $\beta$ or $\alpha$ to get to
\begin{equation}
 \mathbb{E}[(1+\Lambda_i^q)\mid X_0^{i}=x]\leq (1+Cx^q)\quad \text{where }C>0\text{, }q>1\text{ and }x\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

**Edit**: For $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, one can use the sub-gaussianity to follow $\mathbb{E}[e^{\epsilon \sup_{0\leq t\leq T} (\Lambda_t^{i})^2}]\leq C_{T,\epsilon}$, on a time horizon $[0,T]$ and $C_{T,\epsilon}>0$ depending on $T$ and $\epsilon$. Maybe this can be of help.

Comment: Can you briefly explain where you got this problem from? Did you read some book, paper or see some video where you saw a similar argument?

Comment: I found it in the paper "An SPDE Model for Systemic Risk with Endogeneous Contagion" by Hambly et al. in a proof in Chapter 6. They only say that one can get result (1) by applying a simple Gronwall argument considering $|b|\leq C(1+\Lambda)$ and I wonder how to do this. It doesn't seem that simple to me, since the absolute value of $X$ makes it impossible for me to use the expected value to get rid of the stochastic integral and maybe work around a bit with the deterministic integral.

Comment: Thank you very much! Let me take a look at this paper for you.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Do you have any Idea how to approach the problem?

Comment: Ooh, long time ago! I will read the paper and get back today itself.

Comment: Wait, I had a small point here : you have shown that the LHS $\mathbb E[(1+\Lambda^i_t)^q | X_0^i = x] \leq (1+Cx^q)$ for some $C>0$. Taking $C' = \max\{C,1\}$ means that $1+Cx^q \leq 1+C'x^q$ (this is because you won't be taking $x^q$ if $x$ is negative so you'll be having $x^q$ non-negative, and then the domination is clear). Now, $1+C'x^q \leq C'+C'x^q = C'(1+x^q)$. I think this works, and I also think that the small $x$ must be pre-specified as non-negative so that the quantity $x^q$ can be well defined. (Or am I making a terrible error?)

Comment: Sadly, I haven't shown that $\mathbb{E}[...]\leq 1+Cx^q$, that's my question, so you haven't made any mistake in your calculations, but it wasn't my question :D

Comment: OH , I see! Haha, I'd read the paper and thought it was quite monumental that you completed that step. Ok, let's see if I can complete that step, and then my comment above will do the honours. Is that fine? (Also , use @TeresaLisbon to address me as I did not see your earlier comment in time for this reason).